# "USB DEVICE NOT RECOGNIZED" appears in taskbar after connecting smartphone

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, usb

We are connecting Android Smartphone to my laptop, may see "USB Device Not Recognized" in taskbar, but data cable for smartphone is good. Please help! I am use smartphone GT-I8262 and Jelly Bean Version 4.1.2.

Comment: Try to install Kies as Samsung sets need PC suit to connect or if it not works then download adb installer and execute it while connecting your device

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Kies as Samsung sets need PC suit to connect or if it not works then download adb installer and execute it while connecting your device

Answer (score -1):

Try change USB cable and connect to computer to make sure connection works properly. If you doesn't work well, you can buy USB cable at cellphone store.